# jquery submenu: li items still toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours now and as i'm pretty new to jQuery itself and i'm definetely still a beginner i really need some help with this. I try to create a navigation with a submenu in it. Everything is working as intended but i am missing the way i can stop the list items of the submenu from toggling.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
      <ul id="site-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 2 (with submenu)</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 3 (with submenu)</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

**JQuery (submenu part):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var subnavArrow = ['<div id="subnavArrow"></div>'];
      subpull     = $('header nav ul li');
      submenu     = $('header nav ul li ul');
      submenuitems = $('header nav ul li ul li');

  subpull.has('ul').prepend(subnavArrow);

  $('header nav ul li').has('ul').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle('slow');
  });

});
```

If you didn't catch what i mean, i try to explain it as thoroughly as i can:

I want to open the Main Nav Item 2's subitems per click on it (Main Nav Item 2). This is working as intented and i can also close it again, but if i click on a Submenu Item of "Main Nav Item 2" it will close down the Main Nav Item 2's submenu.

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani why should he. All the needed code is for you right in the Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether you have clicked on the `anchor` or `div` element like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var subnavArrow = ['<div id="subnavArrow"></div>'];
  subpull = $('header nav ul li');
  submenu = $('header nav ul li ul');
  submenuitems = $('header nav ul li ul li');

  subpull.has('ul').prepend(subnavArrow);

  $('header nav ul li').has('ul').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('li').is(this)) {
      $(this).children('ul').toggle('slow');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#subnavArrow:after {
  content: '<<'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="site-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 2 (with submenu)</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 3 (with submenu)</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: It works as intended thank you, but can you explain to me the line you added with e.target? Is there a place where i can look this up in more detail or in which situations i should / need to use this (besides on this particular menu)?

Comment: @ricosauney `e.target` refers to the element which triggered the click event - You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target and https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 2):

- Don't append `#ID` elements. ID should be unique. Use classes instead `.subnavArrow`
- Refer in jQuery to `#site-nav` as the parent
- Use `Event.stopPropagation()` (if you'll use more nested li>ul)
- Always assign your `var` to variables, or concatenate using `,`

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready

  var $LIsub = $("#site-nav li:has(ul)");

  $LIsub.children("a").append('<span class="subnavArrow"/>');
  
  $LIsub.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('> ul').slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
#site-nav li ul{
  display:none;
}
.subnavArrow:after{
  content:"\25BC"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul id="site-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Main Nav Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that when you click on a submenu `<li>`, the click event propagates to the parent `<li>`, and triggers the function hiding the `<ul>`.

A solution could be to move the `.has('ul')` part of your click listener inside the callback :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var subnavArrow = ['<div id="subnavArrow"></div>'];
    subpull = $('header nav ul li');
    submenu = $('header nav ul li ul');
    submenuitems = $('header nav ul li ul li');

    subpull.has('ul').prepend(subnavArrow);

    $('header nav ul li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).has('ul')) {
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('slow');
        }
    });

});
```

This way, the listener also listens for the clicks on the submenus, and you can prevent the event from propagating to the parent with `e.stopPropagation();`

You can sere this solution on this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9ejpLmLf/

Answer (score 0):

```
Very simple code
=============================
<pre>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var subnavArrow = ['<div id="subnavArrow"></div>'];
      subpull     = $('header nav ul li');
      submenu     = $('header nav ul li ul');
      submenuitems = $('header nav ul li ul li');

  subpull.has('ul').prepend(subnavArrow);

  $('header nav ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle('slow');
  });

});
</pre>
```